# how to iterate a arraylist of object

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, taglib, foreach

i m using dao design pattern in which i m returning a arraylist object ,inside object  i can fetch by typecasting object into class and acees the getters like object.getName(),i want to itearate using a jstl tags.how can i do that.

Answer (score 4):

```
<c:forEach items="${yourArrayList}" var="item">
    <c:out value="${item.name}" />
</c:forEach>
```

The objects you put in your collection should conform to the JavaBeans specification (for ex. all of their properties should be accessible via getter methods).

`${yourArrayList}` is actually a request attribute that you have put from a servlet and then forwarded to the jsp.

Answer (score 1):

Ok with Bozho.

I will just say that if you redirect a servlet to jsp (which is better than calling dao from scriptlets...) don't forget to put your object that will be used in jstl in a pagecontext scope like request or session. Without that jstl lib would never find your object...